# MYSQL Nested group by using single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db with the following schema

---

```
Id | Employee_Name | Time_Taken | Job_Number | Date
```

---

Finally for any given date range what I want to return is a result of the following form

```
{  
   "Brad":[  
      {  
         "day":"1",
         "avg_time":"1.65"
      },
      {  
         "day":"2",
         "avg_time":"2"
      }
   ],
   "Emily":[  
      {  
         "day":"1",
         "avg_time":"1.65"
      },
      {  
         "day":"2",
         "avg_time":"2"
      }
   ]
   ..
}
```

So I want to show is for each employee the average time taken to complete a job day wise.

What I could think of is to first get all employees and then iterate over employees and for each of them do the following

```
SELECT DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date)), AVG(time_taken)
       FROM PerformanceTable WHERE (date BETWEEN x AND y AND employee_name=name)
       GROUP BY DAYOFMONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date));
```

Please ignore any minor syntactical errors with the query but that is what I have in mind. My question is that, is there any way to do it via a single query without looping over the employees. Thanks !

Comment: Add `Employee_Name` to both `select` & `group by` and remove it from `where`

Comment: You didn't mention it, but, from your 'acceptance', presumably time is stored in integer seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use "day of month" to define day.  Just pull the date component out of the `date` column (assuming that it has a time).

Then, add `employee_name` to the `select` and `group by`:

```
select employee_name, date(from_unixtime(date)) as date,
       avg(time_taken)
from PerformanceTable pt
where date between x and y  -- assumes "x" and "y" are integers, not dates
group by employee_name, date(from_unixtime(date))
order by employee_name, date;
```